# How to tell if there is a statistical difference in some values?

Tags: statistics, statistical-mechanics

I am new in the community and I d like to ask this. Let's assume that i have a sample which is a time series. I want to know if the difference in values has a statistical significant change. An example :

"Has the average BMI of men been increased the last 30 years?"

So i have the time series and i want to know the standard deviation( which i can easily calculate) BUT i want to know the significance of the SDEV.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I think you need this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-test

Comment: I think that this is maybe the answer i will check it thoroughly and then i might delete the answer if it is

Comment: Also this is a possibility: https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda353.htm

Comment: @MattiP. this is a two sample t-test so it will not work. I only got 1 sample and i want to know if there is a change and if that change is statistically different